# Is this a faithful rendition of the selection sort algorithm?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting

I've been reading an elementary book about sort algorithms.  To get my head around it, I tried to write a simple program to implement the algorithm.

EDIT: I had omitted an important line that was in a previous version - see comment below.

This is my selection sort:

```
class SelectionSorter

  attr_reader :sorted

  def initialize(list)
    @unsorted = list
    @sorted = []
  end

  def select(list)
    smallest = list.first
    index = 0
    list.each_with_index do |e,i|
      if e < smallest
        smallest = e
        index = i
      end
    end
    @sorted << list.delete_at(index)
  end

  def sort
    @unsorted.length.times { self.select(@unsorted) }
  end

end
```

Here's a test:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'sort'

class SelectionSortTest < MiniTest::Test

  describe SelectionSorter do

    it 'sorts a randomly generated list' do
      list = (1..20).map { rand(100-1) + 1 }
      sorted_list = list.sort
      sorter = SelectionSorter.new(list)
      sorter.sort
      sorter.sorted.must_equal sorted_list 
    end

  end

end
```

I'd love comments, particularly around whether this is actually a faithful implementation of the algorithm.

EDIT 2:

OK - here's my in-place code.  This is the sort of thing I wanted to avoid, as it feels nastily procedural, with nested loops.  However, I think it's a faithful implementation.

```
class SelectionSorter

  def sort(list)
    sorted_boundary = (0..(list.length)-1)
    sorted_boundary.each do |sorted_index|
      smallest_index = sorted_index
      smallest_value = list[smallest_index]
      comparison = sorted_index + 1
      (comparison..(list.length-1)).each do |next_index|
        if list[next_index] < smallest_value
          smallest_index = next_index
          smallest_value = list[smallest_index]
        end
      end
      unless sorted_index == smallest_index
        list[smallest_index] = list[sorted_index]
        list[sorted_index] = smallest_value
      end
    end
    list
  end

end
```

I'd love to do this in a more recursive fashion, with less stored state, and without nested loops.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You should have a separate question for a different implementation.

Comment: ok! sorry about that!

Comment: Added new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517658/how-can-i-make-this-less-procedural-and-more-ruby-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `smallest = e` immediately after `index = i`, so you are keeping a running tally of the smallest value found so far.

I'd also note that selection sort is usually implemented in-place, i.e., scan locations 1-N of your list for the min and then swap it with the first element, then repeat the process with elements 2-N, 3-N, etc. There's no need for a second array or the expense of removing elements from the middle of an array.

Comment: Aha ok - I had wondered about an in-place implementation.  My approach was more about trying to think through the process.  I'll have a go at that once I've got some test cases in place.

Comment: Okay, good luck with that.  Test cases are good, you can learn a lot from seeing where they cause your code to fail.

Comment: Looking back in history, I actually had the running tally of smallest value in place - not sure how that got dropped.  With that in place, my tests pass.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the selection sort algorithm, but I can tell that your code does not do sorting. In this part:

```
list.each_with_index do |e,i|
  if e < smallest
    index = i
  end
end
```

you end up having as `index` the index of the last element of `@unsorted` that is smaller than the first element of `@unsorted` (If there is no such element, then `index` is `0`). Then, by:

```
@sorted << list.delete_at(index)
```

you take that element from `@unsorted`, and push it into `@sorted`. And you repeat this process. That does not give you sort.

Comment: Aha! I need more test cases!  And a rethink!